# JavaScript: Can anyone get this to work or explain why it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

**Update**

Per the answer from epiqueras, I looked at how I'm handling the import. First, `/models/index.js` is exporting named exports.  Here's the code:

```
'use strict';

import { readdirSync } from 'fs'
import {
    basename,
    extname,
    resolve
} from 'path';


//
// Using module.exports here as a bit of a hack 
// to allow for member imports in the form of
// import { Constructor } from "~/models"
module.exports = readdirSync(__dirname)             // Get contents of current directory
                   .filter(f => f !== 'index.js')   // Exclude the index file
                   .map(f => resolve(__dirname, f)) // Resolve the complete module file path
                   .map(f => require(f).default)    // Require the module
                   .reduce((prev, next) => {        // Reduce the array of modules to a hash of Module.name = Module
                       prev[next.name] = next;
                       return prev;
                    }, {});
```

I derived this from the [requireindex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requireindex) project which did not work for me (no doubt user error).  What I have since discovered is that if I import the class directly, i,e., `import Patron from '../models/patron'` then everything works as expected.

At this point, I have five other models in my project that all export fine using the code above.  `Patron` is the only one that doesn't.  And as stated in the original question, if I change the name to anything else, the code above exports that new name with no issues.

Thankfully, I have a workaround now.  Hopefully I can figure out why it's choking on the name `Patron`.

**Original Question**

I've written a simple class in JavaScript:

```
'use strict'

export default class Patron {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props;
  }

  create() {
    // In my actual code I make a network call,
    // simplified this just to see if anyone can get it to return a promise
    return Promise.resolve(this);
  }
}
```

For completeness, here's an example of how I'm using the constructor:

```
'use strict'

import { Router } from 'express';
import { Patron } from '../models';

const PatronRouter = Router();

PatronRouter.post('/patrons', (req, res) => {
  let patron = new Patron({ name: 'John Doe' });
  let promise = patron.create().then(response => res.send(response);
}

export PatronRouter;
```

And here's what I experience:

- `Patron` is a valid constructor, no errors initializing an instance
- `patron` is an instance of `Patron`
- `patron.props` is `undefinded`
- `patron.create` exists as an instance method
- `patron.create` returns `undefined`

Here's what makes absolutely no sense to me: **if I change the name of the class everything works.** I'm not understanding where/how/why the name `Patron` is causing a problem?

A couple of other notes:

- Running node (6.9.2)
- Part of an Express (latest) app, trying to execute this code from a `Router`
- Using Babel 6 with the `es2015` preset enabled

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the import side of things?  Do you have any other `Patron` symbols anywhere?  Did you look at the Babel generated code to see exactly what the generated code looks like?

Comment: you code seems valid but your expiernence is wrong: `patron.props = defined` and `patron.create => Promise.<Patron>`. probably somewhere in your usage of this code it goes wrong.

Comment: note that if you do an ajax call you shoudln't return `Promise.resolve()` But actually wrap that call into a `new Promise((accept,reject)=> {Your code here})`

Comment: @jfriend00 expanded the import/usage example.  I have not found any other `Patron` symbols anywhere and I'm not entirely sure I know how to look at the babel generated code.  At this point, I'm just learning/debugging through `npm start` with the start script being `nodemon index.js --exec babel-node`

Comment: @JoelHarkes I don't return `Promise.resolve()` in the actual code, that's just for brevity in the example.

Comment: @RyanBach - question states `running node`

Comment: Are you certain you are re-exporting the value properly in `./models/index.js`?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the call to `new Patron` will succeed, since `Patron` is being exported as a default export, but then imported as a named export, which means it will probably be undefined.

Comment: Adding to the good points above, you need [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, otherwise the question can be considered offtopic and be closed. A github repo that can replicate the problem would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exporting the class as a default export, but importing it as a named export.

Try this: `import Patron from '../models`;

Or change the export to a named export: `export class Patron`

Comment: @jfriend00 It doesn't solve my problem, but it does confirm that naming a class `Patron` is not a universal failure. I'm still at a loss at understanding why it is failing in my project.

Comment: @sellmeadog - You can be assured that `Patron` is not a reserved word in Javascript or a pre-defined symbol in node.js.  My guess is that you have another symbol conflicting in your own code or in some code you're importing.

Comment: @epiqueras Per my updates to the original question, your answer helped me find a workaround to my problem which is why I've accepted it.  Still curious as to why my `models/index.js` is choking on `Patron` but I can figure that out later.

Comment: @sellmeadog Have you tried console.logging your reduce code? I think that the reason it works when you change it's name has something to do with the lexicographical ordering of files in the models directory. The order in which Patron gets put in that array might somehow be making it fail. Log after readDirSync, filter, map, map, and reduce and see how Patron is handled.